# Batching technique using Protobufs

Tags: http, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-java

Is there an efficient technique to batch different Protobuf events while sending over HTTP?

The goal is to have a list of multi-type Protobuf messages in one request. One idea I have is to separate messages in small arrays and specify their type to be able to deserialize them on the server.

Answer (score 5):

You can use some `Any` message type combined with `repeated`, as follows:

```
message Any {
    string type_url = 1;
    bytes value = 2;
}

message Envelope {
    repeated Any events = 1;
}
```

Then, in your code:

- when serializing, you must set `type_url` according to the message type that you serialize in `value`
- when deserializing, you must read `type_url` to know which type is contained in `value`, and deserialize accordingly

The example above reproduces the `google/protobuf/any`, that is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any